# MySQL Order By with If Condition Slows Query Down

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I need to use order by with if condition, it needed around 5 seconds to query it.
Can we improve mysql order by with if condition performance?

My query is

```
SELECT product.title
FROM product
INNER JOIN menu
    ON product.menu_id = menu.id
INNER JOIN order
    ON menu.order_id = order.id
WHERE
    product.type = 2
ORDER BY
    (if(order.id=9455,1,0)) DESC,
    (if(product.subcategory=149,1,0)) DESC,
   (if(product.category=123,1,0)) DESC,
    product.id DESC
LIMIT 6;
```

All the specific columns already indexed, so I think it's not index problem.
It return zero second if I remove the if condition in order by

Comment: Because your `ORDER BY` clause includes columns from two tables, it might be hard to come with a single index which covers everything.  Can you include all indices which you have already defined?

Comment: The indices right now is product.menu_id, menu.order_id, product.subcategory, product.category. actually I can configure my indices if you have recommend.